# How do I extend the main distZip so I get a copy of the ZIP file with some extra files in it?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to generate multiple zip files for my project using the application plugin so that I can include OS specific exe files in the zip.
I have the exe files under src/win32/dist and they end up in the win32 zip file fine, but that's all that's in that zip file.

How do I configure my additional distributions so they each include everything in the main zip PLUS these exe files, not just these exe files?

Here's an example bit of config:

```
distributions {
    //I want win32 to include the same as the 'main' dist plus files in src/win32/dist
    win32 { 
        contents {
            from { libsDir }
        }
    }

    amd64 { 
        contents {
            from { libsDir }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the directory structure:

```
src/
    win32/
        dist/
            prunsrv.exe        <-- win32 specific exe
    amd64/
        dist/
            prunsrv.exe        <-- amd64 specific exe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never used 'distribution' or 'application' plugin; But going through the documentation of 'distribution' plugin & Distribution javadoc, I understand that :

1. The distribution automatically pulls in files under `src/<distName>/dist`, which is what you mentioned.
2. Next is to include the contents of the main distribution; For this change your `distributions` as

   ```
   win32 { 
       contents {
           with project.distributions.main.getContents()
       }
   }

   amd64 { 
       contents {
           with project.distributions.main.getContents()
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Sundeep! That's exactly what I needed, and so simple too.

Comment: I have done similar zip like above. Prunsrv.exe is not working after gradle does zip. I have extracted the zip it throws error on running the exe file. What should I do to make it working. I use gradle version 6.3.3. And distribution plugin. Please help.